# Constructor newInstance generates local instance only

Tags: java, reflection

Looks I miss something in my tests (Robolectrics|Powermockito).

I have following class with Singleton:

```
public class Core{

   private static Core instance = new Core();

   public static Core getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }   

   public static void destroy(){
    instance = null;
   } 
}
```

In my tests I kill the `instance` with `Core.destroy()`
and therefore `Core.getInstance()` returns `null`.

So every test I want to re-generate `instance` again. I do the following:

```
Constructor<Core> constructor = Core.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
                constructor.setAccessible(true);
                Core newCore = constructor.newInstance();
```

So now `newCore` is initialized but `Core.getInstance()` still returns `null`.

How to initialize properly `Core` -> `instance`?

Comment: Why not `public static void replaceWithANewInstance() { instance = new Core(); }`?

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't want to write methods for tests purpose

Comment: Btw. that is not a singleton. Not with public constructor.

Comment: @snaggs you don't really want to write brittle, broken reflection code for test purposes either. Is the `destroy()` method actually needed? I don't see why your application code would ever call it.

Comment: @Kayaman right, the destroy for demo only. I use in my tests `Class<?> core = Class.forName(Core.class.getName());    setStatic(core.getDeclaredField("instance"), null);`

Comment: @snaggs what do you mean "for demo only"? I can't imagine any sane reason why you would need to "destroy" a singleton. It gets unloaded when the JVM exits, and during its lifetime it's a singleton (hopefully stateless) that is guaranteed to exist.

Comment: @snaggs "I don't want to write methods for tests purpose" I don't see what possible value there is in production code for something that "nulls out" a singleton. Aside from anything, this doesn't actually destroy the instance - anything that is holding an instance to it will continue to hold it.

Comment: The `destroy()` method does not really destroy anything. It only changes the value returned by subsequent invocations of `getInstance()`. Anyone who still has a reference to the `Core` object, can continue using it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Core {

    private static class SingletonHolder {
        private static AtomicReference<Core> instance = new AtomicReference(new Core());
    }

    public static Core getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.instance.get();
    }   

    public static void destroy() {
        SingletonHolder.instance.set(null);
    } 

    public static void reset() {
        SingletonHolder.instance.compareAndSet(null, new Core());
    } 
}
```

Using an extra "superfluous" inner class is done for concurrent initialisation, ensuring that the static field is initialized once.

Changing the instance (destroy, my reset) needs some kind of synchronisation for objects.
Instead of the more costly `synchronize` one can use an AtomicReference.

`compareAndSet` does not set the instance with a new value, if there is already an old value.

It is also worth having

```
Optional<Core> getInstance() { ... }
```

So the usage is safe-guarded.

```
Core.getInstance().ifPresent(core -> { ... core ... });
```

Comment: @Holger, a copy error from the javadocs, intended `compareAndSet`. Corrected. Added a comment for ignoring the resulting boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the constructor `private` so that code using you singleton class cannot create an instance using it and they should *only* get an instance using the `getInstance()` method.

Also the lifetime of a singleton object is typically tied to the JVM, as there should be a single instance of a singleton class per JVM. So if you can destroy and re-create the instance it is not a true Singleton IMO, so I assume you only want to re-create the instance for testing.

To re-create the singleton from your test classes after calling the `destroy()` method you can get the `Field` of the class having the instance of your class. Using that `Field` you can set it to the new instance you created:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Core.getInstance()); //gets instance
        Core.destroy();
        System.out.println(Core.getInstance()); // null
        reinitializeInstance(Core.class);
        System.out.println(Core.getInstance()); //gets instance
 }

public static void reinitializeInstance(Class<Core> clazz) {
    try {
        Constructor<Core> constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        Core newCore = constructor.newInstance();

        Field field = Core.class.getDeclaredField("instance"); //gets the instance field
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(newCore, newCore);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And your Singleton class:

```
class Core {

    private static Core instance = new Core();

    // To prevent reflection from creating a new instance without destroying the first one
    private Core() {
       if(instance != null){
           throw new IllegalStateException("Instance already exists!");
       }
    }

    public static Core getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static void destroy() {
        instance = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Holger yes as long as I am not exposing those members there is no need to switch it back.

Answer (score 1):

There is an important point that I often try to explain to people when talking about singletons:

*There's a difference between a singleton and something that you will only create 1 instance of*. And, often, when you think you want a singleton, actually you just want something that you will only create 1 instance of.

The difference between these two things is perhaps not apparent at first, but important to realize, especially when you find yourself in a position where you need to purge the internal state of a singleton between tests.

- If you have a singleton - a true singleton - there is, by definition, one instance that can exist in the JVM. If this has mutable state, this is problematic, because it means that you have to care about that state. In tests, you have to clear state between runs to remove any effects owing to the ordering of test execution; and you have to run your tests serially.
- If you use dependency injection (as in [the concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), not any particular framework like Guice, Dagger, Spring etc), it doesn't matter to classes using the instance where that instance came from: you, as a client of the class, get control over its life cycle. So, whereas your production code uses the same instance in all places, your testing code can use separate instances - thus they are *decoupled* - and often you don't even have to worry about cleaning up state at all, because your next test case can simply create a new instance of the class.

So, instead of code using your `Core` class like so:

```
class MyClass {
  void foo() {
    Core core = Core.getInstance();
    // ... do stuff with the Core instance.
  }
}
```

you can write it instead like:

```
class MyClass {
  private final Core core;

  MyClass(Core core) { this.core = core; }

  void foo() {
    // ... do stuff with the Core instance.
  }
}
```

and you have broken the static binding between `MyClass` and `Core`. You can instantiate `MyClass` in tests with separate instances of `Core`:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(new Core());
// Assert something...
```

or, if multiple instances need to interact with the same instance of `Core`:

```
Core core = new Core();
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(core);
MyOtherClass myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass(core);
// Assert something...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this pattern instead?

```
public class Core{

   private static Core instance;

   public static Core getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) instance = new Core();
        return instance;
    }   

   public static void destroy(){
    instance = null;
   } 
}
```

And if you only want to destory in tests, you can remove "public" from your destroy() method

Comment: True, but can be achieved with synhronized on destory() and getInstance()

Comment: Or maybe that cannot be set on static method? My Java is a bit rusty

Comment: Synchronized can be set on static methods but it could hurt performance a bit, there are other solutions. All depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're making Core constructor accessible, but it's public by default already.

Second, when your calling the constructor, it just creates a new instance of Core, which does nothing to instance, because constructor, created by default is empty and because constructor is not the place to initialize Singleton.

If you want to refresh singleton instance you should have a dedicated method for that.